# Calculate angle on bent bar based on height

Tags: trigonometry, geometry

I'm writing a small piece of software that shows a preview of a bent rebar. I am however unable to figure out how to calculate the angle so the shape fits within given height $(B)$ requirements.

$A, B, C, D$ and *R* are known. I'm trying to calculate the angle *V*. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I'm going to use lowercase letters for the parameters and uppercase letters to identify certain points in the picture below.

[image]

From to the picture, we find

- $\overline{OQ} = r+d$
- $\overline{OM} = r+d$

and then the height of the green segment is
$$
\overline{MN} = \overline{OM}\cos\theta + \overline{OQ} =
(r+d)\,(\cos\theta+1)
$$
from which we get the height of the red segment:
$$
\overline{MS} = b - \overline{MN} = b - (r+d)\,(\cos\theta+1)
$$

On the other hand, the length of the blue segment is:
$$
\overline{ST} = [\,a - (r+d)\,]\cos\theta
$$

However, we also have
$$
\tan\theta = \frac{\overline{MS}}{\overline{ST}}
$$
so
$$
[\,a - (r+d)\,]\,\sin\theta = b - (r+d)\,(\cos\theta+1)
\qquad (1)
$$

Now define

> $$
> \alpha \equiv \frac{a}{r+d} - 1
> \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
> \beta \equiv \frac{b}{r+d} - 1
> $$

Since $0 \le b \le a$ and $a > (r+d)$ (see the pictures to understand why), we must have

> $$
> \alpha > 0 \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
> -1 \le \beta \le \alpha
> $$

Then (1) reduces to

> $$\alpha\sin\theta = \beta - \cos\theta \qquad (2)$$

Note that this equation correctly describes some "edge cases":

$\theta = 0 \iff \beta = 1 \iff b = 2(r+d)$

[image]

$\theta = \pi/2 \iff \beta = \alpha \iff b = a$

[image]

$\theta = \pi \iff \beta = -1 \iff b = 0$

[image]

Also, we expect that $\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$, hence $\cos\theta < 0$, for $\beta = 0$. I didn't draw that picture but it isn't difficult to see why that must be true. Indeed, from (2), setting $\beta = 0$, we find $\tan\theta = -1/\alpha$, implying $\cos\theta < 0$ (for $\theta$ in the second quadrant).

However, (2) does not uniquely determine $\theta$ for all possible values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. To see why, consider the situation below. Both positions of the bar have the same values of $a$ and $b$ (hence, same $\alpha$ and $\beta$) but different values of $\theta$.

[image]

Now, back to (2). Squaring both sides, we find
$$\alpha\sin\theta = \beta - \cos\theta$$
$$\alpha^2\sin^2\theta = \beta^2 - 2\beta\cos\theta + \cos^2\theta$$
$$\alpha^2\,(1-\cos^2\theta) = \beta^2 - 2\beta\cos\theta + \cos^2\theta$$
$$(1+\alpha^2)\cos^2\theta - 2\beta\cos\theta + (\beta^2 - \alpha^2) = 0$$
whose solution is

> $$
> \cos\theta =
>  \frac{\beta \pm \sqrt{\beta^2 - (1+\alpha^2)(\beta^2-\alpha^2)}}{(1+\alpha^2)}
> $$

As expected, there are two solutions for each pair $(\alpha,\beta)$.

Comment: Letting a = 160, b = 100, r = 10 and d = 16 and doing an arccos on the solution, I get the angle to 136 degrees, wich is not correct, where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Softnux Hmm... I might have made a mistake somewhere. I did solve it late at night last night, after all. :) I'll check my answer shortly. In the meantime, thanks for looking at it and trying some numbers. I should have done that myself. +1

Comment: @Softnux My mistake was not to have realised that there are always two solutions, both equally valid. With the numbers you tried, you should now get both $\theta \approx 136^{\circ}$ and  $\theta \approx 22^{\circ}$.