# Angle between segments resting against a circle

Tags: circles, plane-geometry

**Motivation**:

A couple of days ago, when I was solving [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393703/calculate-angle-on-bent-bar-based-on-height), I had to consider a configuration like this

[image]

Now, I didn't intentionally make those two yellow bars stand at what appears to be a $90^{\circ}$-angle but it struck me as an interesting situation, so much so that I thought the following question might be an interesting one to solve.

**The Question**:

Given a circle of radius $r$, a horizontal line a distance $c>r$ from the circle's centre, and two points $A$ and $B$ on that line located as indicated in the picture below, find the angle $\Theta$ as a function of the parameters given ($a,b,c,r$). The blue and red lines passing through $M$ are tangents to the circle, at $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

[image]

Comment: Very well - I have deleted my comment - and will delete this soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution of the form $\tan\frac{\theta}{2} = f(a,b,c,r)$.

First, note that $\angle QOM = \angle POM$. This comes from the triangles $OPM$ and $OQM$ being similar. They're both rectangular (at $P$ and $Q$), they share the same hypotenuse ($\overline{OM}$), and $\overline{OP} = \overline{OQ} = r$. This also implies that $\overline{PM} = \overline{QM}$. Let $\xi \equiv \overline{PM}$.

Next, note that $\angle POM = \theta/2$. This results from the above and $\theta + (\pi/2 - \angle POM) + (\pi/2 - \angle QOM) = \pi$.

Next, note that $\tan\left(\angle POM\right) = \overline{PM}/\overline{OP} = \xi/r$, so

> $$
> \xi = r\tan\frac{\theta}{2}
> $$

We'll now seek an equation for $\xi$ in terms of the various parameters of the problem. Note the following relations:
$$
\overline{AM} = \overline{AQ} - \overline{QM} = \overline{AQ} - \xi \qquad (1)
$$
$$
\overline{OA}^{\,2} = \overline{OQ}^{\,2} + \overline{AQ}^{\,2} = r^2 + \overline{AQ}^{\,2}
$$
$$
\overline{OA}^{\,2} = (a-b)^2 + c^2
$$

Similarly,
$$
\overline{BM} = \overline{BP} + \overline{PM} = \overline{BP} + \xi \qquad (2)
$$
$$
\overline{OB}^{\,2} = \overline{OP}^{\,2} + \overline{BP}^{\,2} = r^2 + \overline{BP}^{\,2}
$$
$$
\overline{OB}^{\,2} = b^2 + c^2
$$

Then
$$
\overline{AQ}^{\,2} = (a-b)^2 + c^2 - r^2 \qquad (3)
$$
$$
\overline{BP}^{\,2} = b^2 + c^2 - r^2 \qquad (4)
$$

Now let

> $$
> u \equiv \overline{AQ} = \sqrt{(a-b)^2 + c^2 - r^2}
> \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
> v \equiv \overline{BP} = \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - r^2}
> $$

From (1)-(4) and the law of cosines,
$$
\overline{AB}^{\,2} = \overline{AM}^{\,2} + \overline{BM}^{\,2} - 2\,\overline{AM}\,\overline{BM}\,\cos\theta
\qquad (5)
$$
we see that we'll need $\cos\theta$ in terms of $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$. That's easy:
$$
\cos\theta = \frac{1 - \tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}}{1 + \tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}} = \frac{r^2 - \xi^2}{r^2 + \xi^2}
\qquad (6)
$$

Combining all of the above, we can get a quadratic equation for $\xi$, after some tedius but not particularly difficult algebra:
$$
\left[ (u+v)^2 + 4r^2 - a^2 \right] \xi^2 - 4(u-v)r^2\,\xi + \left[ (u-v)^2 - a^2 \right] r^2 = 0
$$
whose solution is
$$
\frac{\xi}{r} =
\frac{2(u-v)r \pm \sqrt{
4(u-v)^2r^2 - \left[ (u+v)^2 + 4r^2 - a^2 \right] \left[ (u-v)^2 - a^2 \right]
}}{\left[ (u+v)^2 + 4r^2 - a^2 \right]}
$$

The second term inside the radical, *sans* the negative sign, simplifies to
$$
\left[ (u+v)^2 + 4r^2 - a^2 \right] \left[ (u-v)^2 - a^2 \right] =
4r^2(u-v)^2-4a^2c^2
$$
and we find
$$
\frac{\xi}{2r} =
\frac{(u-v)r \pm ac}{\left[ (u+v)^2 + 4r^2 - a^2 \right]}
$$

Thus,

> $$
> \tan\frac{\theta}{2} =
> \frac{2\left[ (u-v)r \pm ac \right]}{\left[ (u+v)^2 + 4r^2 - a^2 \right]}
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> u \equiv \overline{AQ} = \sqrt{(a-b)^2 + c^2 - r^2}
> \qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
> v \equiv \overline{BP} = \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - r^2}
> $$

It's not surprising that there should be two valid solutions, since $Q$ could also be on the side closer to $B$.

Comment: _Very_ nice. I haven't checked the algebra, but even if there _were_ an error I'd expect it just to rearrange the terms somewhat on the right-hand side of the final answer. (By the way, you can accept your own answer and in this case I think you should.)

Comment: Thank you. I did the algebra by hand so it's very possible that I might have made a mistake, though I'm confident I didn't.

Comment: I don't have any reason to suspect an error in the algebra. Just saying that the solution _method_ seems quite robust.

Comment: I understand. When I was doing the algebra, I had a momentary concern because of $\xi^3$ and $\xi^4$ terms popping up but they soon cancelled other terms of the same order. I was really surprised, in the end, by how simple the result is. I wonder if Ramanujan would look at the result and say something along the lines of "That's obviously true because segment XY is the bisector of angle TUV and..."

Answer (score 1):

Set Cartesian coordinates on the plane so that the center of the circle
is $(0,0)$ and the black line $\overline{AB}$ is parallel to the $x$-axis.

The coordinates of $A$ are $(-(a - b), c)$ and the distance $OA$ is
$\sqrt{(a - b)^2 + c^2}$. Therefore 
\begin{align}
\angle OAB & = \arcsin\left( \frac{\sqrt{(a - b)^2 + c^2}}{c} \right)
= \arctan \left( \frac{c}{a-b} \right) & \text{and} \\
\angle OAQ & = \arcsin\left( \frac{\sqrt{(a - b)^2 + c^2}}{r} \right).
\end{align}

The coordinates of $B$ are $(b, c)$ and the distance $OB$ is
$\sqrt{b^2 + c^2}$, so 
\begin{align}
\angle OBA & = \arcsin\left( \frac{\sqrt{b^2 + c^2}}{c} \right)
= \arctan \left( \frac cb \right) & \text{and} \\
\angle OBP & = \arcsin\left( \frac{\sqrt{b^2 + c^2}}{r} \right).
\end{align}

Since $\angle BAM = \angle OAB + \angle OAQ$
and $\angle ABM = \angle OBA - \angle OBP$,
and $\theta = \pi - \angle BAM - \angle ABM$,

\begin{align}
\theta & = \pi - (\angle OAB + \angle OAQ) - (\angle OBA - \angle OBP) \\
& = \pi - \arctan \frac{c}{a-b}
        - \arcsin \frac{\sqrt{(a - b)^2 + c^2}}{r} 
        - \arctan \frac cb
        + \arcsin \frac{\sqrt{b^2 + c^2}}{r} .
\end{align}

---

Another approach: consider the figure below, which shows line $\overline{AB}$
and segments  $\overline{OP}$ and $\overline{BP}$. It also shows the
perpendicular from $O$ to $\overline{AB}$, which intersects $\overline{AB}$
at $C$ and $\overline{BP}$ at $R$.

[image]

From the original problem statement, we have $OP = r$, $BC = |b|$, and $OC = c$.
Let $OR = |u|$, with $u$ positive if $R$ is between $O$ and $C$ as shown. Then $CR = |c - u|$ and $PR = \sqrt{u^2 - r^2}$, and by similar triangles,

$$ \frac{\sqrt{u^2 - r^2}}{r} = \pm\frac{c - u}{b}.$$

There are actually three cases represented here:

1. $b > 0$, shown in the figure;
2. $-r < b < 0$, in which case $R$ is on the extension of $\overline{OC}$ beyond $C$, $u > c$, and $\triangle BCR$ has (positive) leg lengths $-b$ and $u - c$; and
3. $b < -r$, in which case $R$ is on the extension of $\overline{OC}$ beyond $O$, $u < -r$, and $\triangle BCR$ has (positive) leg lengths $-b$ and $c - u = c + |u|$. This is the case that requires the "$-$" option of the $\pm$ sign.

In all three cases I assume $c > r$.

Squaring both sides of this equation and rearranging terms appropriately,
we get:

$$ (b^2 - r^2)u^2 + 2cr^2 u - (b^2 + c^2)r^2 = 0.  \tag 1$$

If $b^2 \neq r^2$ this is a quadratic equation in $u$, and it has roots

$$ u = \frac{-cr^2 \pm br \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - r^2}}{b^2 - r^2}.$$

We want the positive root if $b > -r$ and the negative root if $b < -r$, so

$$ \angle CBP = \arccos \frac ru 
 =
\begin{cases}
\arccos  \dfrac{b^2 - r^2}{-cr + b \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - r^2}}
 & \text{if $b > r$} \\
\arccos  \dfrac{b^2 - r^2}{-cr - b \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - r^2}}
 & \text{if $b < r$ and $b \neq -r$.}
\end{cases}$$

But if $b = r$, then
$ u = \dfrac{c^2+r^2}{2 c} $
and
$$ \angle CBP = \arccos \frac ru 
 = \arccos  \frac{2cr}{c^2+r^2} ,$$
whereas if $b = -r$ then $\angle CBP = \frac\pi2$.

And oh, look, all of these formulas apply to $\angle BAQ$ in the original figure
if we substitute $b - a$ for $b$ 
(and $b - a < -r$ provided that $\angle BAQ$ is acute, as shown), so
if we assume $b > -r$,

\begin{align}
\theta & = \pi - \angle BAQ - \angle CBP \\
& \begin{aligned}
      = \pi & - \arccos  \dfrac{(a - b)^2 - r^2}
                               {-cr + (a - b) \sqrt{(a - b)^2 + c^2 - r^2}} \\
            & - \begin{cases}
                 \arccos  \dfrac{b^2 - r^2}{-cr + b \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - r^2}}
                  & \text{if $b > r$} \\
                 \arccos  \dfrac{b^2 - r^2}{-cr - b \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - r^2}}
                  & \text{if $-r < b < r$} \\
                 \arccos  \dfrac{2cr}{c^2+r^2} & \text{if $b = r$}
                \end{cases}
  \end{aligned} \\
&  = \arcsin \dfrac{(a - b)^2 - r^2}
                   {-cr + (a - b) \sqrt{(a - b)^2 + c^2 - r^2}} \\
& \qquad\qquad +
  \begin{cases}
    \arcsin  \dfrac{b^2 - r^2}{-cr + b \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - r^2}}
     & \text{if $b > r$} \\
    \arcsin  \dfrac{b^2 - r^2}{-cr - b \sqrt{b^2 + c^2 - r^2}}
     & \text{if $-r < b < r$} \\
    \arcsin  \dfrac{2cr}{c^2+r^2} & \text{if $b = r$}
  \end{cases}
\end{align}

So that's just two trig functions, though there are three cases depending
on the value of $b$.
As suggested in a comment, we could get this down to one trig function if
we could find the three sides of $\triangle ABM$ without using trigonometry;
but I think this would involve saying something about the triangles
$\triangle OPM$ and $\triangle OQM$, and I do not yet see how to do it.

Comment: Very nice. +1 for now. I'd like to see an answer that doesn't rely on analytical geometry but if no one rises to the challenge and no other answer is simpler than yours, I'll accept yours.

Comment: @wltrup The Cartesian coordinates are mainly so that I didn't have to redraw the entire diagram just to label the point where the vertical green line intersects the black line. If I had labeled that point $C$ then we would have right triangles $\triangle ACO$ and $\triangle BCO$ and we could just use Pythagoras rather than the Cartesian distance formula.

Comment: True. I'm wondering, though, if there's a way to obtain a simpler version of the result without simplifying it from what you got but "directly" by a different approach. Something along the lines of $\operatorname{trig}\Theta = f(a,b,c,r)$ for *some* trigonometric function $\operatorname{trig}\Theta$ where $f(a,b,c,r)$ does not contain any trig evaluations. Don't know if that's possible at all, however.

Comment: @wltrup I wasn't particularly happy with the first solution either so I tried a new approach. This expresses $\pi - f(a,b,c,r)$ as a sum of two (inverse) trig functions, and I think you can then get $f(a,b,c,r)$ as a sum of two trig functions just by changing arccos to arcsin. Not quite a _single_ trig function, but two is not so bad.

Comment: @DavidK but how angle OAB is equal to arcsin(OA/c). Souldn't we find OB first.

Comment: @user258250 Drop a perpendicular from $O$ to $AB$, you get a right triangle with hypotenuse $OA$ and leg $c$. Angle $OAB$ is opposite leg $c$ (doesn't matter that $B$ isn't in the triangle--what matters is the angle, not which points along its rays we choose to label it with).

Comment: @DavidK Great work. I wish I could give you another upvote [ ok, half of an upvote since you only worked out half of the answer that way ;) ]. Not to throw a wrench but $b$ could be negative too, i.e., $B$ could be to the left of the circle's centre.

Comment: @DavidK I've been thinking about using the law of cosines in $\triangle AMB$ but haven't actually sat down to try anything yet.

Comment: Sorry, @DavidK but I think I did better... :) Impressive work, though, especially in regards to splitting the result for all the possible values of $b$.