# Extending flange on bent bar so horizontal tangent moves to correct place

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm bending a bar as in the image below, but i need to extend the left flange with **x** to get the top of the bend (green tangent at the bend) to move up to the other green line.

**v**, **u**, **a**, **b**, **d** and **r** is known, how do i find **x** (or the distance between the green lines)?

[image: Bent bar]

Comment: See [my answer to this nearly identical question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393703/calculate-angle-on-bent-bar-based-on-height). It should give you a pretty good idea of what to do.

Comment: Could you provide some hints? I am unable to see any thing to go on =/

Comment: @Harish has provided a full solution already below.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Notice, join the left end points of the tangents to the center of circle to obtain right triangle in which we can easily calculate $x$ as follows $$x=(r+d)\cot v-(r+d)\tan \left(45^\circ-\frac{v}{2}\right)$$ 
$$=(r+d)\left[\frac{\cos v}{\sin v}-\frac{\sin \left(45^\circ-\frac{v}{2}\right)}{\cos \left(45^\circ-\frac{v}{2}\right)}\right]$$ 
$$=(r+d)\left[\frac{\cos v\cos \left(45^\circ-\frac{v}{2}\right)-\sin v\sin \left(45^\circ-\frac{v}{2}\right)}{\sin v\cos \left(45^\circ-\frac{v}{2}\right)}\right]$$ 
$$=(r+d)\left[\frac{\cos \left(v+45^\circ-\frac{v}{2}\right)}{\sin v\cos \left(45^\circ-\frac{v}{2}\right)}\right]$$ 
$$=(r+d)\frac{\cos \left(45^\circ+\frac{v}{2}\right)}{\sin v\cos \left(45^\circ-\frac{v}{2}\right)}$$

I hope you can simplify further

Comment: Which are the "the left end points of the tangents"?

Comment: These are the  end points of the green color tangents on the left side of each one.